# NProgress with modal dialog to prevent click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am usign a app using NProgress.js.
Its amazing plugin.

I whanto know it is possible to use with NProgress, a modal dialog ou something like it, to prevent click when NProgress is running in my $.ajax request.

Tks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but the fading effect of the modal obscures the loading bar shown by NProgress. So you may want to attach the loading bar to something other than the 'body' DOM element using something like

```
NProgress.configure({ parent: '#newContainer' });
```

In any case, simply drop a modal block somewhere in the body of the HTML page:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Fetching New Data</h4>
     </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     Please wait...
  </div>
</div>
```

Initialize it in javascript (note that keyboard: false prevents typing from dismissing the modal, backdrop:static prevents clicking to dismiss):

```
$('#loadingModal').modal({ show: false, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static'});
```

Then show/hide it in an Ajax call appropriately:

```
NProgress.start();
$('#loadingModal').modal('show');

$.ajax({...
  }).done(response => {
    // Handle success
  }).fail(err => {
    // Handle errors
  }).always(() => {
    $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
    NProgress.done()
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
 NProgress.inc() 
 $.ajax({...})
  .done(function( data ) {
    ...
    NProgress.done()
  });
```

Remember that you must manage the errors.

Comment: Ok, Execute Nprogress with ajax it's not the problem. The problem is prevent user to click again when ajax request is runnig. i need when i call an request using ajax, all the page or controls set to read only or using something like a page loading "like a modal dialog, to prevent click"